# Reading DNxHD MXF files using Objective-C and mxflib

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos

I'm trying to read MXF files (from Avid) into an Objective-C project and analyze some frames from video.  Preferably getting them into a CGImage or NSImage.

I've been exploring the mxflib, but find myself at a bit of a standstill.  I'm used to the mechanics of the standard video methods within Obj-c, but this package is C++ and not exactly something I'm familiar with.

Does anyone have experience working with this library or another similar one?  There's not much information available on the subject (at least not that I can understand).  And I'm not quite sure where to begin.

Comment: It would seem this is either a very niche or unpopular subject.

Comment: Hi, Did you ever solve this, I'm desperately looking for a solution!  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I'd say you're looking at it from a not so good way, as the mxflib is prepared to handle standard MXF files, not really Avid ones.

In short, for this to work, you need to extend the library as per Avid specs (it can be done!) or go with AMT, for which I understand you need to engage Avid to have it.

Finally, I think you're stuck with C++! ;-)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize DNxHD was so specialized.  Thanks lscn, that was extremely helpful.  And C++ ain't so bad.  I could be stuff with much worse!